# PHP Facebook API Photo Limit

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, limit, photos

I'm trying to get all photos from a defined facebook page. 
https://graph.facebook.com/$pageID/albums?fields=photos.limit(30000)
This only gives me up to a hundred when there's thousands on this particular Mobile Uploads album.

Answer (score 0):

30.000 is way too much, API calls usually have a max limit that is a LOT lower.

Use the paging links in the resulting JSON instead, here is an example from the official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_pagination_basic

Comment: I get Graph returned an error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Comment: well, use an active access token then. "user" is interesting though, you mention "pageID" in your question. there is a big difference between a page and a user profile. make sure you understand the difference, and that you need different tokens for page or user - with different permissions.

Comment: I tried to lookup JSON, and code but I keep getting errors.  Where's a code snipplet on what Im trying to do?

Comment: the question is: where is YOUR code? ;) - and if you get errors, why not add those errors to your question too? you really need to be a lot more specific, stackoverflow is for developers, we can handle clear instructions. in fact, it´s what we require on stackoverflow.

Comment: btw, my answer includes a link to the official docs WITH a code snippet for the php sdk. which is what you are using, according to your tags.